# Using getchar() to Read Two Strings

Tags: c

For the following code, I added two printf statements to test if the two strings are read properly. However, when I enter something like: abcabcabcza,cb
The outputs are:

abcabcabcza▒

cb9

Does anyone know where the symbol at the end of the first string, and the '9' at the end of the second string, come from? Thank you so much!

```
printf("\nEnter two words, seperated by a comma:  ");
int temp1, temp2, index3, index4; char temp3[20], temp4[20];
index3=index4=0;
while((temp1 = getchar())!= ','){
    temp3[index3++] = temp1;
}
printf("\n%s", temp3);
while((temp2 = getchar())!= '\n'){
    temp4[index4++] = temp2;
}
printf("\n%s", temp4);
```

Comment: You need to add '\0' at the end of string so that printf knows where to stop printing. temp3[] and temp4[] have undefined value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Fill out temp3[] and temp4[] with 0

Comment: So the '\0' 's are not automatically inserted to temp3 and temp4? I have to add '\0' at the end of each? Also, why does this matter? I'm ending my loops with the occurrences of the comma and \n, respectively.

Comment: the weird characters are garbage values, as you were told put the '\0' at the end of the string

Comment: Also, you will need to protect the code from abuse -- what happens if there is no comma in the first 19 characters of the line, or no newline within 19 characters of the comma?  At the moment, the answer is "bad things happen -- arrays are written out of bounds
.

Comment: change to `char temp3[20]={0}, temp4[20]={0};`

Comment: RE: BLUEPIXY, that took care of the problem! So if I don't initialize all the values of the array to 0, garbage values will be assumed?

Comment: If you do not initialize like this, You must set the terminator(`'\0'`) explicitly. E.g. `temp3[index3]='\0'` after While-Loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add string terminators `'\0'` to your string before printing (or zero out the buffers memory first).

Also: you have declared buffers of size 20, but have no guards in your code to respect that allocated length, which means you could overrun them and corrupt memory. [Run with two words greater than 20 characters...]

Answer (score 1):

'\n' and '\0' are different here. You need to add '\0' at the end of string because printf prints out string until it meets '\0'. C doesn't initializes array. If you do not initialize manually it will have garbage values.

I would do:

```
char temp3[20] = {0};
char temp4[20] = {0};
```

to fill out temp3 and temp3 with 0, which is same as '\0'.

Comment: That (`temp3[20] = 0;`) is bad; the maximum valid subscript is `temp3[19]` etc.  Even fixing that, it is bolting the stable door after the horse has bolted.  There are problems with overrunning the strings -- or no check to ensure that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

The string in C requires to be NULL-terminated.
A lot of functions use that **terminator** to announce the processor  where the string ends.

What will hapan if not terminated? Lets get one simple string, with consumpption of 5 bytes of memory.

`...[?][?][H][e][l][l][o][?][?][?]...`

That causes a leak. As you see we haven't store a NULL. It causes u/b and you may get different signs on any new run. For us.. the processor puts the string in random blocks of memory. However gcc by default has optimizations to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

when you give a string as 'abc' it will be saved as 'abc\0',so check for \0 also and dont print it